# how to reload component in webpage without reload whole page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to load a single component in my webpage when another component is changed

```
<input ..... onchange="callFunctionToReloadNextTag()">
<input ... />      <--This is the tag i want to reload
```

Can you reload the actual component itself and not just what is in the component?

And when I say reload the component itself i mean... If A = name then B = TextField, If A = date then B = DateField

**EDIT**

This is what i have so far

```
<script>
function checkForChange() {
var approvalStatus = document.getElementById('licensingStatus').value;
if(approvalStatus == "Pass"){
    document.getElementById('licensingApprovalDate').setAttribute("validators", "validators:maxDateToday,required");
} else {
    document.getElementById('licensingApprovalDate').setAttribute("validators", "validators:maxDateToday");
}   
}
</script>
```

This is changing is adding new attributes to the tag correctly but the change is not being picked up on the webpage

Answer (score 2):

Ajax just means "Making an HTTP request from JavaScript without leaving the page"

You can make an HTTP request to a web service that gives you some data, and then modify the DOM to change an input based on that data.

Comment: because the thing is that i have the page retrieving data and making a change but the change is not being picked up at all... how do you mean 'modify the DOM'?

Comment: "i have the page retrieving data" — How?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you've made an attempt to do something and it doesn't work, then your question should be of the form "This is what I want to achieve. This is how I'm going about it. X happens but I expect Y to happen" … Don't just take three steps back and ask if it is possible.

Comment: yes but i have made the changes that i want to the page, now i just need to find out how to reload that component that is changed (if it was possible)

Answer (score 0):

Call the function and do the ajax operations on that function and change the child content using DOM using element ID..

refer this page http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/ajax.html

Comment: Don't use innerHTML. You'll blow away all the other controls there. Use standard DOM and replaceChild.

Answer (score 0):

A new answer because the old one seems to have been obsoleted by edits to the question.

- There is no Ajax there at all
- There is no "validators" attribute anywhere in HTML

I'm going to hazard a guess that you have some function which runs on page load and looks for your non-standard markup, and then assigns event handlers based on that.

You need to change that code so it can handle changes in that non-standard attribute.

This might involve writing a function that will remove all the event handlers it assigns on page load, and then rerunning the assignment function.

Comment: i am using tapestry, that is why i am adding validators, but that doesnt really matter as i need to update the component after the validators have been added to the tag

Comment: It really does matter since you want to change the way tapestry interacts with the control.

Comment: i can use just html and use tapestries If Else statement function and it works but only after you reload the page so i come accross the same problem so i can do it that way but need to reload the component when the change is made instead of reloading the whole page